# Have problem to prove the following inequality

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, expectation

Hi I'm working on the measure theory and probability, I'm totally confused by the following question. Need help. Suppose $0<a<b$, show $$E(|X|^a)\le(E(|X|^b))^\frac{a}{b}$$ from **measure theory prospective (lebesgue-integral)**

Comment: Use Hölder with $p=b/a$.

Comment: I have never met Hölder before, what is Hölder?@amsmath

Comment: The Hölder inequality says that when $f\in L^p$ and $g\in L^q$ (where $1/p+1/q = 1$), then $fg\in L^1$ and$$\int|fg|\,d\mu\,\le\,\left(\int|f|^p\,d\mu\right)^{1/p}\left(\int|g|^q\,d\mu\right)^{1/q}.$$

Comment: Here you can use Hölder with $f=X^a$ and $g=1$.

Comment: Or use the more basic Jensen's inequality $E[h(Y)] \geq h(E[Y])$ for a convex function $h$, such as $h(x) = x^{b/a}$ for $x \geq 0$.